# Minimum value of an integral with least square?

Tags: integration, least-squares

I have a problem. The question is: given a parabola $$p(t) = a + bt + ct^2$$ I need to evaluate the least squares straight line $$A + Bt$$ for which this integral is minimum:

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(p(t) - A - Bt\right)^2 dt $$

How could I solve this? I don't understand well.. :(
Thanks to everybody!!!

Comment: Can you calculate the integral? Then you will see how it depends on your parameters ($a,b,c,A,B$) more easily.

Comment: Possible hint: when the integral reaches its minimal value, its derivative is 0. That plus the fundamental theorem of calculus might help.

Comment: I still don't understand. The fundamental theorem of calculus states that (in my case) i'll have F(t_2) - F(t_1). But in that way what counts? I will have a difference between the same function evaluated in the two different points (t_2 > t_1) and..? o.O I need or an example or the WHOLE answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I can calculate the integral but it's quite a mess.. I mean it should be:

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(a + bt + ct^2 - A - Bt\right)^2 dt$$

I can make che shifts $\alpha = a - A$ and $\beta = b - B$ in order to get a simpler form:

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left(\alpha + \beta t + ct^2\right)^2 dt$$

in that way I can (Should I?) expand the bracket:

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 t^2 + c^2 t^4 + 2\alpha\beta t + 2\alpha ct^2 + 2\beta ct^3 \right) dt $$

and now?

Comment: I mean: it is a mess.. and I don't think the result should be

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$ E(A,B)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(p(t) - A - Bt\right)^2 dt $$

You want to minimize  $E(A,B)$   thus

Find : $$\frac{\partial}{\partial A} (E(A,B))= 0$$
       $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial B} (E(A,B))= 0$$
And then solve $A,B$

$$  \frac{\partial}{\partial A} (E(A,B))=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial A}( \left(p(t) - A - Bt\right)^2) dt$$

$$  \frac{\partial}{\partial B} (E(A,B))=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial B}( \left(p(t) - A - Bt\right)^2) dt$$

Hope it helps

Comment: you/it did!! Thanks a lot!!